# Connect docker container with SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, docker

I'm trying to run code that writes on a SQL Server database.
The code is working fine on my machine (Microsoft).

dockerfile:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM ubuntu:22.04

WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y apt-utils \
    && echo 'debconf debconf/frontend select Noninteractive' | debconf-set-selections

RUN apt-get install -y locales \
    && localedef -i en_US -c -f UTF-8 -A /usr/share/locale/locale.alias en_US.UTF-8 \
    && localedef -i it_IT -c -f UTF-8 -A /usr/share/locale/locale.alias it_IT.UTF-8
ENV LANG it_IT.utf8

RUN apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip

RUN apt-get install -y unixodbc-dev libodbc2

COPY ./src .

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

CMD [ "python3", "-m" , "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0", "--port=5000"]
```

application-docker.cfg file:

```
SECRET_KEY = 'xxx'
ALLOWED_FILES = ['xls']

MAX_RUNNING_JOBS = 3

STORAGE_PATH = '/tmp'

DRIVER = 'SQL Server'

SERVER = 'xxx'

DB_NAME = 'xxx'

USER_ID = 'xxx'

PSW = 'xxx'
```

It raises this error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

I've tried to replace DRIVER with DRIVER = '/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql18/lib64/libmsodbcsql-18.3.so.1.1' but it raises quite the same error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql18/lib64/libmsodbcsql-18.3.so.1.1' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

Tried also by using DRIVER = 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' and in the docker file

```
RUN apt-get install -y msodbcsql17 mssql-tools
```

but when I build the image:

> 0.915 E: Unable to locate package msodbcsql17.
> 0.915 E: Unable to locate package mssql-tools

Comment: You're misunderstanding what's 0.0.0.0 stands for. It's a special address means any local host address, when the program is running in a docker container you'll probably get an internal ip address that only belongs to the container itself. However, your SQL Server normally on a separate server with a different ip address, which means you've specified a wrong SQL Server address to connect to. You'd better figuring out the real SQL Server address that your program need connect to.

Comment: If you must have `mssql-tools` inside the container then you have to follow the Microsoft instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-tools?tabs=ubuntu-install&view=sql-server-ver16#ubuntu (note different Ubuntu version) or get an existing Docker container with `mssql-tools` in it.

Comment: @Horsing I've replaced the 0.0.0.0 in the line  `CMD [ "python3", "-m" , "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0", "--port=5000"] `  with the ip address found with  `SELECT CONNECTIONPROPERTY('local_net_address')  ` but it gives me "Cannot assign requested address"

Comment: @darked89 I don't know if I must have it, I'm trying by using infos that I'm finding online, but I don't even know what I'm doing

Comment: `DRIVER='SQL Server'` only sort-of kind-of works on Windows when people have the legacy and deprecated SQL Server Native Client (v10 or v11) drivers installed. On Linux systems and/or Docker containers you need to install `ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server` or `ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server` as per the distro-specific instructions at [Install the Microsoft ODBC driver for SQL Server (Linux)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server). Note that you have to add references to Microsoft's signing key & repo before apt-get install.

Comment: @fadericofkt It should be the address of SQL Server not local address. Trying to login to SQL Server and execute ipconfig to get all ip addresses and try to ping it from your program container to check the connectivity.

Comment: I solved using @AlwaysLearning answer, if you want you can post it and I'll accept it as the correct one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must have `mssql-tools` inside the container then you have to follow : [the Microsoft instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-tools?tabs=ubuntu-install&view=sql-server-ver16#ubuntu)

(note different Ubuntu version) or get an existing Docker container with mssql-tools in it.

The basic commands (Ubuntu 22.04 version) are:

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.asc

curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/22.04/prod.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mssql-tools18 unixodbc-dev
```

One can also try one of existing  [mssql-tools Docker images](https://hub.docker.com/search?q=mssql-tools) but these may be outdated (most popular is 7 years old) / unknown quality / different Linux distros